# Creating a User Defined Point Grid

Tags: wgs84, decimal-points

Im trying to write some code (in C#, but any language will do) where the user defines and area, based on Min/Max Long/Lat's, and specifies a distance between points in meters, and the code returns a table of long/lats (WGS84/ESPG:4326) to create a grid.

I wrote some code a while ago that I was under the impression did the job, but after a quick bit of analysis, doesnt *quite* measure up to the job.  Please see the code below:

```
decimal minX = -74.002747535706M;
decimal minY = 40.722282672831M;
decimal maxX = -73.98386478424M;
decimal maxY = 40.733470232685M;
decimal distance = 100;
decimal x = 0.0M;
decimal y = 0.0M;
decimal length = 0.0M;
decimal lengthIncrease = 0.0M;

decimal increasePercentage = 0.0M;
int i = 0;

decimal yIncrement = distance / (decimal)111111.111111;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Longitude" , Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
dt.Columns.Add("Latitude" , Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));

y = minY;

while (y < maxY)
{
    while (x < maxX)
    {
        length = (decimal)111.325 * (decimal)Math.Cos((double)y * (double)0.0174532925199433);
        increasePercentage = (decimal)0.001 / length * 100;
        lengthIncrease = increasePercentage / 100 * distance;
        x += lengthIncrease;
        i++;
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Longitude"] = x;
        dr["Latitude"] = y;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    y += yIncrement;
    x = minX;
}

return dt;
```

The above works fairly well.  It returns long/lats seperated by 100m lat, but by 90m long.  When i change the `distance` to 25m, it seperates latitude by 25m, but longitude by 22.3m.

**EDIT**:  C Sharp Version Solution Based on yosukesabai Answer:

```
int radius = 6378137;
double pi = Math.PI;
double deg2Rad = pi / 180;
double dst2Lat = 360 / (2 * pi * radius);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID" , typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Longitude", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
dt.Columns.Add("Latitude", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));

x = minX;
y = minY;
while (y < maxY)
{
    double rLat = radius * Math.Cos(deg2Rad * y);
    double dst2Lon = 360 / (2 * pi * rLat);
    while (x < maxX)
    {
        i++;
        x += dst2Lon * distance;
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = i;
        dr["Longitude"] = x;
        dr["Latitude"] = y;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    x = minX;
    y += dst2Lat * distance;
```

Any help here would be fantastically helpful!

Regards

AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took ASPMapper's approach but instead of doing math on my own, used geodesic package from PROJ.4 (python binding pyproj, http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/).

```
from pyproj import Geod

minX = -74.002747535706  # in degrees
minY = 40.722282672831
maxX = -73.98386478424
maxY = 40.733470232685

distance = 100  # in meters

g = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
coords = []
lon,lat = minX,minY
while lat < maxY:
    while lon < maxX:
        coords.append((lon,lat))
        east = g.fwd(lon, lat, 90, distance)
        lon, lat = east[:2]
    lon = minX
    north = g.fwd(lon, lat, 0, distance)
    lon,lat = north[:2]

for lon,lat in coords:
    print lon, lat
```

**REVISED**

```
from math import pi, cos
minX = -74.002747535706  # in degrees
minY = 40.722282672831
maxX = -73.98386478424
maxY = 40.733470232685

distance = 100  # in meters

# radius of earth, dont tell anybody that i am not using wgs84 :p
r = 6378137
deg2rad = pi / 180

# factor to convert meter to degree of latitude
dst2lat = 360 / (2*pi*r)

coords = []

# start with LL corner
lon,lat = minX,minY

# march Northward
while lat < maxY:

    # radius of circle of latitude
    rlat = r * cos(deg2rad * lat)

    # factor to convert meter to degree of longitude
    dst2lon = 360 / (2*pi*rlat)

    # march Eastward
    while lon < maxX:

        # store results
        coords.append((lon,lat))

        # go distance meter to East
        lon += dst2lon * distance

    # done with one latitude parallel
    # prepare for the next parallel
    lon = minX # roll back to western edge
    lat += dst2lat * distance # go distance meter to North


for lon,lat in coords:
    print lon, lat
```

**Revised again**

Now I tried to incorporate eccentricity of earth defined in WGS84, instead of sphere approximation.  In north/south, i got very good precision (7 digits or so) but on line of latitude i still got 4 digits precision...

```
from math import pi, cos, sin, sqrt
minX = -74.002747535706  # in degrees
minY = 40.722282672831
maxX = -73.98386478424
maxY = 40.733470232685

distance = 100  # in meters

# major axis and inverse of flattening of earth, Now I am using WGS
a, invf = 6378137.0, 298.257223563

# conversion factor between degree and radians
deg2rad = pi / 180

# earth eccentricity
f = 1/invf
e = sqrt(f*(2-f))

# meridional cuvature at the middle latitude of entire box
midY = .5*(minY+maxY)
r_meridional_mid = a * (1 - e*e) / ((1 - (e*sin(midY * deg2rad))**2)**1.5)

# factor to convert meter to degree of latitude, at the middle lattitude
dst2lat_mid = 360 / (2*pi*r_meridional_mid)

coords = []

# start with LL corner
lon,lat = minX,minY

# march Northward
while lat < maxY:

    # normal curvature at the latitude
    r_normal = a / sqrt(1-(e*sin(lat*deg2rad))**2)

    # radius of circle of latitude
    rlat = r_normal * cos(deg2rad * lat)

    # factor to convert meter to degree of longitude
    dst2lon = 360 / (2*pi*rlat)

    # march Eastward
    while lon < maxX:

        # store results
        coords.append((lon,lat))

        # go distance meter to East
        lon += dst2lon * distance

    # done with one latitude parallel
    # prepare for the next parallel
    lon = minX

    # procede approximatedly half distance to North
    lat_tmp = lat + dst2lat_mid * distance * .5
    # get meridional curvature at middle latitude of a row
    r_meridional = a * (1 - e*e) / ((1 - (e*sin(lat_tmp * deg2rad))**2)**1.5)
    # factor to convert meter to degree of latitude
    dst2lat = 360 / (2*pi*r_meridional)
    # procede to North using curvature at cell mid-point
    lat += dst2lat * distance


print "lon,lat"
for lon,lat in coords:
    print "%s,%s" % (lon,  lat)
```

**Revised (Fix radius of normal curvature calc)**

Found why i screwed up radius of normal curvature (i copied formula wrong).  Fixed it and longitude matches with results with Proj.4 by like 9 digits.  Also I "improved" latitude by calculating radius of meridional curvature at cell mid-latitude, not the mid-latitude of entire box.  It is still approximation, correct way should use elliptic integration or something.  Error accumulates in longitudinal direction as I march northward, and endied up by 6digits accuracy in sample input, referring to proj.4

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have the luxury of not doing the maths on my own. Informative for others though!

Comment: fair enough, i got rid of proj library.  how is it now?

Comment: +1 It's a good start.  However, there are realistic cases where the result may be a surprise: you won't always get a rectangular grid of points.  The solution is to precompute how many rows and how many columns are needed and then, by looping over the row and column indexes, force the output to have that many rows and columns.

Comment: @whuber:  with that method, you wont cover the four corners, i.e., (minX,minY), (minX,maxY), (maxX,maxY), (maxX,minY), and you are going to either leave gap near the pole, or exceeds the range near the equator, or fudge with size of grid.  I though that doesn't satisify what was required, which is to cover the user specified range of lon/lat by grid of specified resolution.

Comment: I'm not referring to extreme cases, but to cases much like that contemplated here: small areas not near the poles.

Comment: I am going to revise my answer following way:  decide how many rows i can fit in first.  Then for each row decide how many columns i can fit into at most.  then decide if i am going to have even # of columns or odd across rows (i want to stick to either one, so that adjacent rows will fit nicely when i change # of cols across those rows), by selecting majority.  adjust ncols of minorities by subtracting 1.  Now for each row I place grid point in symmetry leaving some gap near the both end to fit cells within the boundary.  Hope OP post this layout, or want to have her opinion.

Comment: i have edited my query with my C# version of your code.  It doesnt appear to work if im honet.  My points are now 30KMs(!) from each other rather than 100m or there abouts.  However, thsi is more than likely a confusion in the translations.  I have no python experience, and was mildly confused with regard to the nested loops.... where do they loop?  Could you add indentation please?  Also, was your version of this code prducing the correct results?

Comment: I think it is indented correctly so dont know what to do.  I added more comments if it helps.  I thought the algorithm mirrors your approach (start with LL corner, go to east to the edge, then move to north and repeat).  I also added sample output.  I think the coordinate looked reasonable considering that I am using sperical earth. error was like a few percent, when the distance between points are measured by geodesic tool.

Comment: also, pasted code here too [http://python.codepad.org/04yF0Al6](http://python.codepad.org/04yF0Al6)

Comment: Changed a bit of code and it seems to work!  Thankyou very much for your help!  Hope it helps others too!

Comment: I now tried to use WGS84, as specified in the original post.  Improved but seems that there still is some error somewhere for longitude calculations...  Maybe I shouldn't use Normal curvature but something else?